# Making NPM show compilation date

Tags: javascript, npm, jsx

While

```
      npm run watch
```

is running in the background it is possible to see every time I make a change to the jsx code a recompilation process. Is it possible to make npm to show the last time a jsx file was compiled?

thx

Comment: `npm` doesn't know anything about complication. It's only a package manager. You should look at the documentation of the transpiler you are using.

Answer (score 0):

`npm run watch` runs an arbitrary command defined in the `scripts` property of your `package.json` You'll need to look at what command that is actually running to determine if there are further options you can add.

For instance, if you are using `webpack`, then the script might be `webpack -w` or `webpack --watch`, in which case you could add `--verbose` to the end of the script entry `webpack -w --verbose`. Then `npm run watch` would dump out pretty much every stat `webpack` is tracking.